# How can this question be clarified?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

An [old question of mine](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/96/28) was recently closed as "primarily opinion-based".  Please help me clarify the question, because the question intends not to ask for any opinions by any stretch at all.

The purpose of the question is to gain an understanding of what benefits are extended to Social Security members in Mexico. I mention one such benefit ("avoiding the hassle of sending medical bills to my US-based insurance provider"), and ask if there are others.

Is this intent unclear? How can I clarify?

I find the only explanation offered in comments to be completely baffling:

> The answer to this depends on many personal experiences, including perhaps taste.

I don't understand how personal experience, and even less, personal taste, might affect what services the Mexican Social Security system would offer to an expat member.

Or perhaps such questions are now deemed off-topic? If so, perhaps someone could enlighten me as to why?  I would also kindly request that a moderator open, then re-close the question with the proper close reason, for the benefit of future visitors.